# Error while reading an xlsm file using POI Framework in Java

Tags: java, excel, xlsm

I am not able to read an xlsm file using the POI Framework (HSSF). I am getting the following error while reading an xlsm file.

The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

I tried reading the file through XSSF also. Even that doesn't solve the problem. Can anyone tell me how to read a xlsm file in java code using the poi framework and write a new sheet to that file.

Answer (score 4):

First download these JARs and add them in build path:

- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
- poi-3.9.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar

Now you can try this code.  It will read XLSX and XLSM files:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class ReadMacroExcel {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
     //Create a file  from the xlsx/xls file
          File f=new File("F:\\project realated file\\micro.xlsm");

          //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
          org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
          System.out.println(workbook);

     //printing number of sheet avilable in workbook
     int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
     System.out.println(numberOfSheets);
     org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet=null; 
   //Get the  sheet in the xlsx file
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {


      sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
     System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());

   //Iterate through each rows one by one
     Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
     while (rowIterator.hasNext())
     {
         Row row = rowIterator.next();
         //For each row, iterate through all the columns
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

         while (cellIterator.hasNext())
         {
             Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
             //Check the cell type and format accordingly
             switch (cell.getCellType())
             {
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                     System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                     break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                     System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                     break;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("");
     }
 }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }


    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for .xlsm files and Outofmemory exception occurs

Comment: Works great.  You must be having a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using apache-poi.

I used the following code to read my xlsm file

```
FileInputStream fileIn=new FileInputStream("d:\\excelfiles\\WeeklyStatusReport.xlsm");

Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn);      //this reads the file

final Sheet sheet=wb.getSheet("Sheet_name");  //this gets the existing sheet in xlsmfile
//use wb.createSheet("sheet_name"); to create a new sheet and write into it
```

Then you can use Row and Cell classes to read the contents

Finally to write do this

```
FileOutputStream fileOut=new FileOutputStream("d:\\excelfiles\\WeeklyStatusReport.xlsm");
wb.write(fileOut);
```